# Is the term avatar unique to Hinduism?

Tags: avatars

Is the term avatar unique to Hinduism?

Alterntively it is used as a general term to mean different concepts?

Answer (score 1):

We can examine its meaning in Sanskrit this way.

> Avatara = Ava + Tara
>
> Tara means "Brilliantly Shining Far Away Luminous Point" (~star in the
>   sky)     Ava means "Coming Down"

In other words, it is the highest/ultimate reality taking a temporary name & form in the empirical world for fulfilling a particular task and merge back (Avatara PariSamapthi) when the task is completely fulfilled.

Example: In Vaishnava Tradition when Lord Vishnu is The Supreme Eternal Reality, Rama & Krishna are his Avataras.

Comment: Actually some Vaishnavas belive Krishna is the origin.

Comment: @Wikash_ I don't understand why did you bring that up?